# php codeigniter uploading photos

Tags: image, codeigniter

So I was watching a video on how to upload photos using codeigniter. The link I used is here and the code is also at this site http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation--net-9452. I got everything to work however, when I tried to use the code on my own website I ran into a problem.

Basically all I changed was that I created a template for the view to be loaded in instead of just loading a single view. There is a controller Gallery.php file that looks like the follows.

```
<?php
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {

        $this->load->model('Gallery_model');

        if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
            $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
        }

        $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images();


        $this->load->view('gallery_view',$data);

    }
}
```

I simply changed this code to. Really only changing the last line and replacing it with those new three bottom lines.

```
<?php
class Gallery extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {

        $this->load->model('Gallery_model');

        if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
            $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
        }

        $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images();

        $var = $this->load->view('gallery_view',$data,true);

        $data['center_content'] = $var;
        $this->load->view('includes_main/template',$data);

    }
}
```

Now I get an strange error that I do not understand and no error shows up in the console log. Here is a picture of the error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p5kU.png. The error says "unable to load the requested file" then doesn't have any file name after it. then there is a .php at the bottom of the page. I just don't have a clue what is giving me this error. I checked my template over again and again, but don't see anything wrong.

My template is as follows. I commented out everything just to make sure nothing else was giving me this error. So I am just left with one line.

```
<?php $this->load->view($center_content); ?>
```

Thanks for reading. Sorry I just have been stuck on this for a while and still haven't been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there there are many mistakes. you did not load upload library and you also did not set config array. you can find on `codeigniter` user guide how to upload a file. I recommend to you read this link to upload a file in `codeigniter`

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply. I really appreciate the helpp. I'm not sure if I fully understand though. Why is it that the first controller I posted works, but the second one doesn't? I would think that since the first controller works the second one would as well since I only changed that one thing. I mean I have a model file and everything to do all the upload stuff.   Thanks again.